# how can ı use NOT IN query on view file

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

how can ı use NOT IN or '!' on view file,

my Model is like this :

```
public function r_books($read){
$q=$this->db->select('*')
            ->from('books')
            ->where('read',$read)// 0 => is not read, 1 => begin the book, 2 =>finish the book
            ->get();

        return $q->row();
    }
```

this method gets books which are read;

but ı want to get books of which are finished, Not read or beginning books  on view file with this code

```
$books=$this->Model->r_books('!2')
echo $books->read; // this code is get just 'is not read books' data, Not get of  'beginning books' data
```

have you got any suggestions?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

NOT IN and where != are 2 different things that can achieve similar results.

But I would just suggest, in your case,

```
->where('read !=', $read);
```

then: `$this->Model->r_books('2')`

More: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Fyi for NOT IN:

```
$names = array('Frank', 'Todd', 'James');
$this->db->where_not_in('username', $names);
// Produces: WHERE username NOT IN ('Frank', 'Todd', 'James')
```

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html